# How to I set the broker URI in application.properties for Quarkus, Camel and AMQ

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus, quarkus-native

I'm working on porting over an old spring boot application to Quarkus and I've found that my application is not recognising the broker.url property.

I've got this in my pom along with quarkus and camel:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-activemq</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm looking at how to go about setting the broker URL within the properties file and any documentation I try to find on it, directs to me either AMQP or something else, but there isn't anything explicit mentioned for doing this with camel-quarkus-activemq.

Can anyone confirm if there is a way to do this or do I need to specify a bean with the URI exposed?

To set the context, this project will be deployed within Openshift as a native application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set it via `camel.component.activemq.brokerURL=xxx` in the `application.properties`.

You can do this kind for any of the components.

Comment: Excellent, worked a treat. Thanks!